# dotnet ef scaffold login fails for user sa on a SqlServer MacOS/Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, macos, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm executing this command, and definitely using the correct password, but yet it keeps telling me that the login failed.

My password is using a special character ($), and I've read that I should be using quotes to make a string literal, but it does not work on MacOS/Linux.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.;Database=MY_DB;Trusted_Connection=False;User ID=sa;Password=$MYPASSWORD" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -c "DbContext"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to escape the `$` on the connection string, you should be escaping the string using `\` as such `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.;Database=MY_DB;Trusted_Connection=False;User ID=sa;Password=\$MYPASSWORD" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -c "DbContext"` instead.

Comment: what is the use of "-c "DbContext""? getting error as "Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'c' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Connection -ContextDir -Context -ContextNamespace."

Answer (score 9):

I came across this issue.

Switch out your double quotes for single quotes and you should be able to execute in terminal.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 'Server=.;Database=MY_DB;Trusted_Connection=False;User ID=sa;Password=$MYPASSWORD' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -c "DbContext"
```

Here is a link to special characters that need to be escaped. 
https://askubuntu.com/a/278695/325994

Comment: My password contained a bang, and escaping it did not help.  Also surrounding the password with escaped quotes did not work.  Swapping the outer double quotes for single, and additionally using unescaped double quotes around the password worked.